Custom Copilot in PowerApp
Is it more efficient to use Copilot or create a custom copilot to answer survey questions? How can i link PowerApp to my custom copilot? Do i need to use powerautomate to establish the logic behind answering questions
I have not built the custom copilot yet but thinking which way is more efficient

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think if your requirements are not getting fulfil from  existing copilots then create new once. Check this video link showing steps to create custom copilot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFpG3-n36sA
